# Pegar valores anteriores de uma variável caso o valor atual seja 0 com um condição usando o dplyr no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho uma base de dados da seguinte forma:

```
CNPJ    data    dataquebra  alto
2222    201603  201711      s
2222    201511  0           s
2222    201702  201711      s
2222    201704  201711      s
3333    201601  201711      s
3333    201509  0           s
3333    201512  0           s
3333    201607  201711      s
3333    201706  201711      s
1111    201701  201711      s
4444    201503  201605      s
4444    201503  201605      s
9999    201605  201712      s
9999    201511  0           s
9999    201704  201712      s
9999    201603  201712      s
```

Preciso filtrar os valores que a variável `alto` está como `s`. Desejo que todos os valores de `dataquebra` para cada `CNPJ` sejam iguais. Mas percebam que alguns destes valores são iguais a zero.

Assim, substituir as ocorrências de `dataquebra` que sejam iguais a 0 pelo outro valor que não seja 0 nessa variável.

Pensei em usar o `dplyr` e comecei da seguinte forma:

```
library(dplyr)
dados<-dados %>%
  group_by(CNPJ) %>%
  filter(alto=="s") %>%
  mutate(x_lag = lag(dataquebra, order_by = data))

dados<-dados %>%
  group_by(CNPJ) %>%
  filter(alto=="s") %>%
  mutate(x_lead = lead(dataquebra, order_by = data))

dados$dataquebra<-ifelse(dados$dataquebra==0 & !is.na(dados$x_lag), 
dados$x_lag, dados$dataquebra)
dados$dataquebra<-ifelse(dados$dataquebra==0 & !is.na(dados$x_lead), 
dados$x_lead, dados$dataquebra)
```

Mas por algum motivo não deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tua intuição estava correta. Dá sim pra usar o `dplyr`:

```
dados %>%
  filter(alto=="s") %>%
  group_by(CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(dataquebra2 = max(dataquebra))
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   CNPJ [5]
    CNPJ   data dataquebra alto  dataquebra2
   <int>  <int>      <int> <fct>       <dbl>
 1  2222 201603     201711 s          201711
 2  2222 201511          0 s          201711
 3  2222 201702     201711 s          201711
 4  2222 201704     201711 s          201711
 5  3333 201601     201711 s          201711
 6  3333 201509          0 s          201711
 7  3333 201512          0 s          201711
 8  3333 201607     201711 s          201711
 9  3333 201706     201711 s          201711
10  1111 201701     201711 s          201711
11  4444 201503     201605 s          201605
12  4444 201503     201605 s          201605
13  9999 201605     201712 s          201712
14  9999 201511          0 s          201712
15  9999 201704     201712 s          201712
16  9999 201603     201712 s          201712
```

Para não perder informação e ficar mais didático, criei uma outra coluna chamada `dataquebra2`.

Veja que usei o `mutate` como tu, mas a função que escolhi para substituir os valores 0 foi a função `max`. Afinal, se todas as ocorrências de `dataquebra` forem positivas (e creio que sejam), sempre que este valor for diferente de 0, é ele que vai ser escolhido como máximo.